# Show that the initial speed of gun and the shell are in the inverse ratio of their masses

Tags: homework-and-exercises, newtonian-mechanics

A shell of mass $m$ is fired horizontally by a gun of mass $M$  which is free to recoil
and which is on horizontal ground. Show that the initial speed of gun and the
shell are in the inverse ratio of their masses.

Here is my attempt is there anything wrong please tell me?

$v$: velocity of shell relative to the gun

$u$: velocity of the gun

them by conservation of momentum

$m(v-u)-Mu=0$

since $z=v-u$ is  initial speed of shell, $\frac{m}{M}= \frac{u}{z}$
is it correct?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Both velocities (shell and gun) have to be with respect to an observer stationary on the ground (an inertial reference frame). So your use of (v - u) for the shell for the conservation of momentum is correct, since this is the velocity of the shell in the inertial frame.